# BigInteger Sorting, Complexity O(n)

Tags: java

The function 'bigSorting' takes BigInteger input as a 'List of Strings'. I have a single loop approach to sort the String List in the given complexity but still, the string is not sorted/ the BigInteger List is not sorted.

INPUT:
(List of Strings)
31415926535897932384626433832795,
1,
3,
10,
3,
5

```
public static List<String> bigSorting(List<String> u) {
    // Write your code here
        String S = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i<u.size()-1; i++)
        {
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(u.get(i));
            BigInteger b = new BigInteger(u.get(i+1));
            int x = a.compareTo(b);
            if(x>1)
            {
                S = u.get(i);
                u.set(i,u.get(i+1));
                u.set(i+1,S);
                i = -1;
            }
        }
        
        return u;

    }
```

OUTPUT:
(Wrong Answer)
31415926535897932384626433832795,
1,
3,
10,
3,
5

Comment: Lowest sort complexity is O(logN), you can't sort in O(N).

Comment: @plalx O(NlogN) *

Comment: A "single loop" approach can't sort.

Comment: @Slaw Oops indeed, O(NlogN) .. typo.

Comment: OP's code is O(N^2) anyway because it resets the index back to 0 any time it makes a swap

Comment: Even when corrected, this will still be the slowest sorting method known to man. Firstly, you should convert your `Strings` to `BigIntegers` in a prior pass over the input, not every time you do a comparison. Secondly, allowing `List` as the input type allows it to be a `LinkedList`, and you shouldn't sort linked lists directly: you should convert them to an arrays sort the array, then convert the array back to a list.

Comment: @plalx Actually you can, but it takes at least O(N) extra space. Radix sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
int x = a.compareTo(b);
if(x>1)
```

This conditional will never pass. [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger)) for `compareTo` say

> Returns: -1, 0 or 1 as this BigInteger is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val.

So `x` may be `1` but it will never be greater than `1`. You probably meant `x > 0`.

P.S. it appears you have implemented a [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which is an O(N^2) algorithm, not O(N).

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice the loop mistake there.